# Reducing amount of data on remote server

Tags: storage, data

I have a vague question.. which is hard to Google on, so using stackexchange might be more useful.

The current situation is

- local computer: Ubuntu 16.04, not much storage space (~100 Gb)
- Remote server: Ubuntu 18.04, a lot of storage space (~2 Tb), but also a lot of users.
- Communication: via ftp/ssh
- Current application: run models for a couple of days on the remote server

I have a lot of datasets on a remote server (in total 1.5 Tb), but I dont use all of it at all times. I do have a large 8 Tb harddisk at home.
I could transfer only the necessary files onto the server, but doing that everything I want to change my dataset can take quite some time. Is there some smart way to use my local harddisk as 'temporary' storage for the remote server? Again, without too much data overhead?

The only solution I have is to make the local harddisk a 'shared folder' for the remote server by connecting it to my local computer. In this way the remote server should be able to access the data, but I guess this means that I need to keep my computer on when I run my models. And I still suffer from data transportation time.

Comment: For such amounts of data, it would be better if you could allocate a separate disk at the remote site. Talk to you manager and IT staff (assuming this is for work).

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah this is indeed for work. I was thinking the same thing.. but since IT can take quite some time. I was hoping for a solution that I could implement myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You would have to weigh the waiting times against each other. Waiting for 1.5 TB to transfer to the local disk, and then back again for use with the program while it's running, or waiting for IT to install your disk and copy the data locally.